# estimating copying 1GB file from one USB flash memory to second USB flash memory

Tags: usb, computer-architecture

Into host USB (image below) there are plugged two flash memories.  I would like to estimate minimal time of copying one file 1GB to second flash memory.

[image]

It is fairly difficult for me, I assume velocity of read: 40MB/s and velocity of write 30MB/s.
USB High Speed is USB 2.0 and works in half-duplex mode.

Could you help me estimate this time ?

**My attempt** is:
Time for write:  1000MB/30MB = 33s
Time for read: 1000MB/40MB = 25s.
25s + 33s/2 = 25s + 17s = 42s
As you can see, I divide by 2 due to half-dulpex.

Comment: What's your estimate? Show some working out stuff.

Comment: I did add my attempt.

Comment: The most important question is if the receiving device can actually sustain 30 MB/S for a full gigabyte.  Many will start to slow down.  It may be better to do an actual test, both reading from the source  device, and maybe also one reading from /dev/null or similar.

Comment: I fail to see how this is in _any_ way on topic. You're having problems using your memory sticks in a PC, it should be migrated to superuser.

Comment: You say "minimal"? You want a guaranteed number x such that copying will always take at least x seconds? In that case, pick the most optimistic estimates of USB throughput and you'll never be disappointed by faster copy times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to divide the write time by half? Under your (optimistic) assumptions of Write rate of 30MB/s and 40MB/s for Reads, the answer is simple: in BEST case your application layer will take 25s to read the ENTIRE file, and then 33s to write it back to another drive. So it will take 25+33=58s total, and not a second less. This is the most optimistic estimate under your basic ASSUMPTIONS for data transfer rates. If your application layer has smaller buffer, reads and writes will go in smaller chunks in interleaving manner, so the transfer time will be somewhat longer due to protocol(s) overhead.

ADDENDUM: I guess the confusion comes from wrong assumption that each port in the shown card operates as independent channel. It is not. All EHCI controllers are implemented as "root hubs", meaning that each controller has only one list processor (aka DMA), and all HS ports share the same 480Mbps bandwidth. To get reads/writes to go in parallel, one needs to install two cards in system. Or more.

Answer (score 1):

First, USB 2.0 has a raw data rate of 480Mb/s=60MB/s. The real data rate is a little lower.

And half-duplex means that only one device on a bus can send data at a time.

Now, it depends on your hardware. If this card really has four independent USB controllers, one USB bus is used for reading, and one for writing (simultaneously), and none of them is operated at the limit of 60MB/s. And the PCIe databus is so fast, you don't have to care about.
The bottleneck then is the writing USB stick of 30MB/s, and it takes about 33 seconds.

If the card has only a single USB controller and a 4x USB hub, all the data has to go twice (and not simultaneously) through that single USB connection between hub and controller. The "writing" stick can receive data at 30MB/s only, and data from the "reading"  stick will be requested at a rate of 30MB/s, too. Here, 30MB/s+30MB/s=60MB/s, and since 2GB are transferred over a single USB bus, it again takes 33 seconds.

However, the realistic data rate of USB 2.0 is lower. If it's 50MB/s, it takes about 42 seconds.

And in general, it can take a few more seconds since e.g. the computer first buffers some data from the "reading" USB stick before sending it to the "writing" stick.

Comment: You're overestimating the realistic data rate of USB 2.0. I think about 42 MB/s is the fastest transfer rate you can practically get. There's a "master" question [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24700/why-are-usb-devices-slower-than-480-mbit-s), with a somewhat evasive answer.

Comment: Plus the computing overhead. USB doesn't have dma or direct peer to peer transfers. All data has to go through the pc, significantly bogging it down compared to fire wire or thunderbolt/lightning transfers.

Comment: The above answer is based on all wrong assumptions and total unawareness of facts. (1) The controller is PCI, not PCIe. (2) The historical EHCI controllers (implemented by VIA and NEC/Renesas, as well as USB controllers implemented in INTEL products) are architected as "root hubs", meaning that all HS ports are broadcasting USB data, just like a separate high-speed hub will do. Therefore there is no simultaneous reads from one device while writing to another.